# Error while login with Facebook and OAuth in ROR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, oauth

Ok, guys, I give up. 
I create Rails app and want login with facebook.
I watch railscast, read a few tutorials and more then 20 questions on stackoverflow... but still i can't login with fb on my site..
so, please, help me with this problem...

Gemfile

```
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'koala', '~> 1.10.0rc'
```

config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, Rails.application.secrets['APP_ID'], Rails.application.secrets['APP_SECRET'], { scope: 'user_about_me' }
end
```

index.html.slim

```
h2 Welcome
= link_to 'Login with Facebook', '/auth/facebook'
```

Facebook -> Developers -> MyApp -> Settigns
Basic:
[image]

Settings Advanced
[image]

And after 'Login with Facebook' link and confirm in popap I have error:

> Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not permitted by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

Can somebody explain me, what's wrong with Facebook or with my hands?

UPDATE: 
ok, another error: 
When `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` set to `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback/`, FACEBOOK respond with error `Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not permitted by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.`

But when `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` set to `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback` (without '/' at the end), I have OAuth2 error: `OAuth2::Error
: {"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"EYOCCnhlcFv"}}`

Comment: Try using this http://localtunnel.me/
it will expose your local instance to the web and facebook will have easier time dealing with it as poper URL.

Comment: tnx, but how this will help fix my problem? i want other peoples can login to my website with FB.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to fix this somehow? I'm having hopes that this will work when I deploy the app but this is irritating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently broken. There is a pr out to fix the gem right now.

https://github.com/gioblu/omniauth-facebook/commit/eff97bfae32f72821cbccf0b48b78351e41eb585

Comment: good news, everyone! my hands are allright! :) ok, wait for merge. if i change gem localy - will it work correctly?

Comment: Yeah, if you change it locally you can get around it until it's in the official.